# Enable MPTCP on mininet host

Tags: mininet

I have a quick question. I installed MPTCP v 0.89 via http://multipath-tcp.org/ on my ubuntu 14.04 machine. I see it performs well. Now, I'm trying to run mininet and create a certain network topology with multiple hosts in the virtual network on the machine. In this case, is the host in the virtual network capable of using MPTCP? If not, how can I enable the hosts to use the MPTCP Please let me know if you have any information. It will be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got my own answer. Yes, you just install MPTCP on the kernel and you can use MPTCP extension inside mininet networks on the mininet host without any additional installation.